# Delete setup.exe after finish install on click once

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I would like to know if it´s possible to delete the setup.exe of clickOnce after installs the program, or to limit the installation to a certain number of installs... all on clickonce deployment... the delete process I would like to include it in the setup.exe, is possible to include a script that can accomplish that task?

Comment: Yes, you can delete the setup.exe after it installs the program.

Comment: Do I have to include a script or there is any documentation that you could point me to?